# Server with Multiple Clients: how to forward message from one client to another

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I have a working server that can handle multiple clients (one thread per client) - adapted from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/internet/singleServerMulClient.asp). At the moment it works like this:

1. Client connects to server
2. User types message on client console which is sent to server (and displayed on server-side console.
3. User types message on server console which is sent back to the same client.

But what I would like to do is receive a message from e.g. client 1, which goes to the server for processing, and then may be forwarded to client 3 (which client it forwards the message to is determined by server).

My guess is that I need to modify the `clientHandleThread`, but I don't know what I need to do. I'm also not sure if it is possible to access a separate thread from the current one.

I am very new to socket programming and threads, and trying hard to learn and so would welcome any help! I am attaching the code containing `main()` (please let me know if I should attach other code!)

```
myLog winLog;

DWORD WINAPI clientHandleThread(LPVOID threadInfo)
{
    //this structure will contain all the data this callback will work on
    myThreadArgument* clientArgument = (myThreadArgument*)threadInfo;

    //the semamphore to protect the access to the std output
    mySemaphore* coutSemaphore = clientArgument->getCoutSemaphore();

    /*get the client connection: receiving messages from client and
    sending messages to the client will all be done by using
    this client connection*/
    myTcpSocket* clientConnection = clientArgument->getClientConnect();
    string clientName = clientArgument->getHostName();

    //the server is communicating with this client here
    while(1)
    {
        string messageFromClient = "";

        //receive from the client

        int numBytes = clientConnection->receiveMessage(messageFromClient);
        if ( numBytes == -99 ) break;

        //write to the console and the log file, so lock the semaphore
        coutSemaphore->lock();

        cout   << "[RECV fr " << clientName << "]: " << messageFromClient << endl;
        winLog << "[RECV fr " << clientName << "]: " << messageFromClient << endl;

        msgInfo proMsgFrCli = msgClassification(messageFromClient);

        //if the client wants to discount
        if ( messageFromClient.compare("quit") == 0 || messageFromClient.compare("Quit") == 0 )
        {
            coutSemaphore->unlock();
            break;
        }
        else // send to the client
        {
            char messageToClient[MAX_MSG_LEN+1];
            memset(messageToClient,0,sizeof(messageToClient));
            cout << "[SEND to " << clientName << "]: ";
            cin.getline(messageToClient,MAX_MSG_LEN);
            winLog << "[SEND to " << clientName << "]: " << messageToClient << endl;
            clientConnection->sendMessage(string(messageToClient));
            coutSemaphore->unlock();
        }
    }

    // if we reach here, this session with the client is done,
    // so we set the event on this thread to inform the main
    // control that this session is finished
    clientArgument->getExitEvent()->setEvent();
    return 1;
}

DWORD WINAPI serverHandleThread(LPVOID threadInfo) //server thread
{
    //this structure will contain all the data this callback will work on
    myThreadArgument* serverArgument = (myThreadArgument*)threadInfo;

    //the semamphore to protect the access to the std output
    mySemaphore* coutSemaphore = serverArgument->getCoutSemaphore();

    //get the server
    myTcpSocket* myServer = serverArgument->getClientConnect();
    string serverName = serverArgument->getHostName();

    //bind the server to the socket
    myServer->bindSocket();
    cout   << endl << "server finishes binding process... " << endl;
    winLog << endl << "server finishes binding process... " << endl;

    //server starts to wait for client calls
    myServer->listenToClient();
    cout   << "server is waiting for client calls ... " << endl;
    winLog << "server is waiting for client calls ... " << endl;

    //server starts to listen, and generates a thread to handle each client
    myThreadArgument* clientArgument[MAX_NUM_CLIENTS];
    myThread* clientHandle[MAX_NUM_CLIENTS];
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_CLIENTS; i++ )
    {
        clientArgument[i] = NULL;
        clientHandle[i] = NULL;
    }
    int currNumOfClients = 0;
    char buffer [100]; //temp buffer to convert currNumOfClients to char

    while ( 1 )
    {
        //wait to accept a client connection.  
        //processing is suspended until the client connects
        myTcpSocket* client; //connection dedicated for client communication
        string clientName; //client name 
        client = myServer->acceptClient(clientName);    
        clientName = clientName + "-" + itoa(currNumOfClients, buffer, 10);//char(65+currNumOfClients);

        //lock the std out so we can write to the console
        coutSemaphore->lock();
        cout   << endl << endl << "==> a client from [" << clientName << "] is connected!" << endl;
        winLog << endl << "==> a client from [" << clientName << "] is connected!" << endl << endl;

        coutSemaphore->unlock();

        //for this client, generate a thread to handle it
        if ( currNumOfClients < MAX_NUM_CLIENTS-1 )
        {
            clientArgument[currNumOfClients] = new myThreadArgument(client,coutSemaphore,clientName);
            clientHandle[currNumOfClients] = new myThread(clientHandleThread,(void*)clientArgument[currNumOfClients]);
            serverArgument->addClientArgument(clientArgument[currNumOfClients]);
            clientHandle[currNumOfClients]->execute();
            currNumOfClients++;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    /*build a semaphore so we can synchronize the access to std cout
    also includes the log file*/
    mySemaphore coutSemaphore(string(""),1);

    //initialize the winsock library
    myTcpSocket::initialize();

    /*create the server: local host will be used as the server, let us 
    first use myHostInfo class to show the name and IP address 
    of the local host*/
    winLog << endl;
    winLog << "retrieve the local host name and address:" << endl;

    myHostInfo serverInfo;
    string serverName = serverInfo.getHostName();
    string serverIPAddress = serverInfo.getHostIPAddress();
    cout << "my localhost (server) information:" << endl;
    cout << "   name:    " << serverName << endl;
    cout << "   address: " << serverIPAddress << endl;
    winLog << "     ==> name: " << serverName << endl;
    winLog << "     ==> address: " << serverIPAddress << endl;

    //open socket on the local host(server) and show its configuration
    myTcpSocket myServer(PORTNUM);
    cout   << myServer;
    winLog << myServer;

    //read connectivityFile
    neighbourInfo = connFrFile(numberOfFiles, intBtwnChange);
    //read routingFile
    nextHopInfo = routFrFile(numberOfFiles, intBtwnChange);

    /*create a thread to implement server process: listening to the socket,
    accepting client calls and communicating with clients. This will free the 
    main control (see below) to do other process*/
    myThreadArgument* serverArgument = new myThreadArgument(&myServer,&coutSemaphore,serverName);
    myThread* serverThread = new myThread(serverHandleThread,(void*)serverArgument);
    serverThread->execute();

    // main control: since the serverThread is handling the server functions,
    // this main control is free to do other things.
    while ( 1 )
    {
        /*do whatever you need to do here, I am using Sleep(x) 
        to make a little delay, pretending to be the other 
        possible processings*/
        Sleep(50000);

        //report the server status
        coutSemaphore.lock();
        cout   << endl << "-----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        winLog << endl << "-----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout   << "server (name:" << serverName << ") status report:" << endl;
        winLog << "server (name:" << serverName << ") status report:" << endl;
        cout   << "   the following clients have successfully connected with server: " << endl;
        winLog << "   the following clients have successfully connected with server: " << endl;
        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_CLIENTS; i ++ )
        {
            myThreadArgument* clientInfo = serverArgument->getClientArgument(i);
            if ( clientInfo ) 
            {
                cout   << "         " << clientInfo->getHostName() << endl;
                winLog << "         " << clientInfo->getHostName() << endl;
            }
        }
        cout   << "   the following clients have shutdown the connection: " << endl;
        winLog << "   the following clients have shutdown the connection: " << endl;
        for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_CLIENTS; i ++ )
        {
            myThreadArgument* clientInfo = serverArgument->getClientArgument(i);
            if ( clientInfo && clientInfo->getExitEvent()->waitForEvent(0) )
            {
                clientInfo->setSignalToEnd(true);
                cout   << "         " << clientInfo->getHostName() << endl;
                winLog << "         " << clientInfo->getHostName() << endl;
            }
        }
        cout   << "-----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        winLog << "-----------------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        coutSemaphore.unlock();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each connection you can have two queues: One for input, and one for output. The connections thread (if you have one dedicated thread per connection) reads input from the client and puts it in the input queue. The connection-thread also fetches messages from the output queue and sends it to the connected client.

The server then has another thread, that goes through all connections input queues, extracts the messages, decides what to do with the input, and then possibly puts it into the output queue of some other connection.

---

Pseudo-code example:

```
struct message_struct
{
    int source;       // Source where the message came from
    int destination;  // Destination client to send message on to
}

void client_thread()
{
    while (!exit_thread)
    {
        if (is_there_anything_to_recv())
        {
            // Receive and parse a message from the client
            message = receive();

            // Add to the threads input queue
            add_to_queue(input_queue, message);
        }

        // As long as there are messages in the output queue
        while (!queue_is_empty(output_queue))
        {
            // Remove one message from the queue
            message = remove_from_queue(output_queue);

            // And send it to the connected client
            send(message);
        }
    }
}

void server_thread()
{
    while (!exit_thread)
    {
        // Check for new connections
        // ...

        // Assuming the threads are on array (or array-like structure)
        for (i = 0; i < number_of_client_threads; i++)
        {
            // While the current threads (`i`)  input queue is not empty
            while (!queue_is_empty(client_threads[i].input_queue))
            {
                // Remove the message from the threads input queue
                message = remove_from_queue(client_threads[i].input_queue);

                // And add it to the destinations output queue
                add_to_queue(client_threads[message.destination].output_queue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to have a queue - my apologies for not knowing more about this. Is there already a queue implemented in my program (I do not think so, but perhaps I have this wrong)?

My understanding from your answer is that 

1/ under the clientHandleThread, I will need to implement queues where it currently receives and sends messages to a client
2/ there is currently one existing server thread and I will need to add one more that takes care of this queueing?

And I wish I knew more about this subject, but would you know a good example to do this? (and thank you for helping so far!)

Comment: @sccs Added a simple pseudo-code example on how it _might_ be implemented. As for queues, it's one of the most basic data structures after arrays and lists.